# Uncaught TypeError: $.alert is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to customize the alert but it keeps showing an error that "$.alert is not a function"

`jQuery(function($) {
    "use strict";

```
$.user_login = function() {
    $('.btn-login').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var loginData = {};
        $this.parents('.login-panel').find('input').each(function() {
            loginData[ $(this).attr('name') ] = $(this).val();
        })

        $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': '/user-login',
            'data': loginData,
            success : function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $.alert({
                        title: '',
                        type: 'red',
                        content: '<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Missing Field.',
                        typeAnimated: true
                    });
                    return;
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log('LoginError:', e);
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery.user_login();
}); )};
```

Is there anything wrong with my codes?

Comment: IMO you can't overwrite window alert using this way. There must be some documentation for your approach.

Comment: But I already done that before, and it's working properly. I don't know now why it is not working.

Comment: Please check your work history Or share jQuery version which you've used before.

Comment: it's all the same, that's why i dont know why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Please check a few things:

- The version of jQuery that ships with WordPress is run in
  noConflict() mode.Meaning you have to use jQuery instead of $ when you make your first reference.
- Don't register your own version of jQuery when you're developing.
  You're locking yourself in to a single version that may or may not be
  compatible with WordPress' other requirements.
- You can use the browser console to test things. Open your page, then
  hit F12 to launch the console. Type jQuery into the console and see
  whether or not it returns the correct object.

It is worth to check according to the Bootstrap .js declaration if required (after jQuery) i.e.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I already done that earlier and it's still not working.

Comment: is it custom lib?